Problemas al obtener bordes con Canny y Probabilistic Houg Lines de una imagen de celdas solares con EL
Estoy tratando de segmentar una imagen de un panel solar en las distintas celdas que tiene. Para ello, se realizan algunos pasos con su respectiva visualización. Antes que nada, se recorta la sección del panel y se eliminan los bordes del panel para solo extraer la región en la que estoy interesado.
La imagen que estoy utilizando es esta:

import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Cargar la imagen en escala de grises
I = cv2.imread("..\\panel1.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Verificar si la imagen se cargó correctamente
if I is None:
    print("Error: No se pudo cargar la imagen. Verifica la ruta y la integridad del archivo.")
else:
    # Paso 1: Reducir ruido con desenfoque Gaussiano
    Ib = cv2.GaussianBlur(I, (5, 5), 0)

    # Paso 2: Aplicar umbral de Otsu
    _, IB = cv2.threshold(Ib, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # Paso 2.5: Dilatar la imagen para cerrar el divisor central
    kernel = np.ones((15, 15), np.uint8)  # Tamaño ajustable según el divisor
    IB_dilated = cv2.dilate(IB, kernel, iterations=1)

    # Paso 3: Encontrar contornos en la imagen dilatada
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(IB_dilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Paso 4: Identificar el contorno con el área más grande (panel completo)
    max_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # Obtener las coordenadas de la caja delimitadora (bounding box) del panel completo
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(max_contour)

    # Extraer la región del panel completo usando la caja delimitadora
    panel_region = I[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # Mostrar resultados
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

    plt.subplot(1, 4, 1)
    plt.title("Imagen Original")
    plt.imshow(I, cmap='gray')

    plt.subplot(1, 4, 2)
    plt.title("Imagen Umbralizada")
    plt.imshow(IB, cmap='gray')

    plt.subplot(1, 4, 3)
    plt.title("Imagen Umbralizada y Dilatada")
    plt.imshow(IB_dilated, cmap='gray')

    plt.subplot(1, 4, 4)
    plt.title("Región del Panel Extraída")
    plt.imshow(panel_region, cmap='gray')

    plt.show()


Después, en el segundo paso, se intentan dibujar las líneas horizontales y verticales. Para hacerlo en la región localizada del panel, aplicamos el método de detección de bordes de Canny, seguido de la técnica de líneas probabilísticas de Hough, utilizando un valor de umbral adaptativo calculado a partir de la intensidad general de una imagen de electroluminiscencia (EL). La umbralización de Otsu se aplica a la imagen del panel porque separa las regiones oscuras y claras iterando a través de todos los valores de umbral posibles y calculando una medida de dispersión para los píxeles que caen en el primer plano o en el fondo. Para identificar los bordes reales en una imagen del panel, aplicamos valores de umbral alto (Th) y bajo (Tl). Cualquier borde con un gradiente de intensidad mayor que Th se considera un borde, y aquellos por debajo de Tl se descartan al considerarlos no bordes.
Sin embargo, el error que estoy obteniendo es que se grafican muchas lineas horizontales, pero no están correctamente dibujadas en los bordes de las celdas. Adjunto una imagen de lo que se quiere lograr, pero el código no está produciendo el resultado esperado.

Este es el código:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
import extract_region


Ip = extract_region.panel_region
panel_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(Ip, (5, 5), 0)

def enhance_contrast(image):
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (25, 25), 0)
    contrast_img = cv2.divide(image, blurred, scale=255)
    enhanced_image = cv2.equalizeHist(contrast_img)
    
    return enhanced_image

panel_enhanced_contrast = enhance_contrast(panel_blurred)

def suppress_non_max_and_skeletonize(image):
    otsu_thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
    binary = image > otsu_thresh
    skeleton = skeletonize(binary).astype(np.uint8) * 255
    
    print("Skeleton de Supress_Non_Max", skeleton)
    return skeleton

panel_skeletonize = suppress_non_max_and_skeletonize(panel_enhanced_contrast)



# Calcular umbrales alto y bajo de manera adaptativa
average_intensity = np.mean(panel_skeletonize)
otsu_thresh = cv2.threshold(panel_skeletonize, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[0]
Th = max(otsu_thresh - (average_intensity / 2), 0)  # Aseguramos que no sea negativo
Tl = max((otsu_thresh / 2) - (average_intensity / 2), 0)

# Aplicar detección de bordes de Canny
edges = cv2.Canny(panel_skeletonize, int(Tl), int(Th))

# Detección de líneas horizontales y verticales usando HoughLinesP
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, threshold=200, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=200)

# Preparar figura para mostrar los resultados
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 8))
axs[0].imshow(Ip, cmap='gray')
axs[0].set_title("Región del Panel")

axs[1].imshow(edges, cmap='gray')
axs[1].set_title("Detección de Bordes (Canny)")

# Dibujar líneas en la imagen del panel
panel_with_lines = cv2.cvtColor(Ip, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
if lines is not None:
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        # Filtrar solo líneas horizontales y verticales
        angle = np.abs(np.arctan2((y2 - y1), (x2 - x1)) * 180 / np.pi)
        if angle < 10 or np.abs(angle - 90) < 10:  # Horizontal o vertical
            cv2.line(panel_with_lines, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)

axs[2].imshow(panel_with_lines)
axs[2].set_title("Líneas Horizontales y Verticales")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

Por último, esta es la imagen que devuelve al utilizar Canny y Hough

